# What does it mean to set data-target attribute of a div to the id of that div?

Tags: html

I'm reading some code and there is a piece of html that reads:

```
<div id="uniqueId1234" data-target=".uniqueId1234">
    ...
</div>
```

and then earlier on in the same html file there is a span element that seems to use this div as a class:

```
<span class="uniqueId1234">
    ...
</span>
```

Can someone explain how this works? I thought that a class was something created in a css file. Sorry if this is a dumb question.

Answer (score 2):

This is likely part of some piece of Javascript code or a library that listens for some type of change or event on your element with the `data-target` attribute.

When this event is triggered, it can then use the value of that attribute as a selector for performing some other logic as seen in this basic jQuery-based example below:

```
// When an element containing your data-target attribute is clicked
$('[data-target]').click(function(){
     // Find the appropriate target (i.e. ".uniqueId1234")
     var target = $(this).data('target');
     // Then use it as a selector for some type of operation
     $(target).toggle();
});
```

Classes are very common within CSS to style multiple elements, but they can also commonly be used as a mechanism in Javascript as well, which is likely the case in your scenario here.

Answer (score 0):

> What does it mean to set data-target attribute of a div to the id of that div?

Nothing standard. `data-*` attributes are designed to hold custom data for custom code (typically client side JS) to process.

> I thought that a class was something created in a css file.

Classes are an HTML feature used to put elements into arbitrary groups. They are commonly used when writing CSS, but also client side JS and other code.